# Как передать data-id в переменную php скрипта?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Необходимо передать `ID` секции `data-elementor-id` в переменную `php` скрипта, который по этому `ID` получает данные из базы.

Вот пример кода:

```
<div data-elementor-type="section" data-elementor-id="1012">
<section class="container page-intro">
    <div class="header-text__links"><?php  the_breadcrumb() ?></div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h1><?php echo get_post_meta(1012,'title', true );?></h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <p><?php echo get_post_meta(1012,'text', true );?></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>      
</div>
```

Comment: Параметр один хотите передать, или таких будет много?

Comment: параметр один, но таких блоков с уникальными ID на странице много)

Comment: Если параметров было бы мало - можно было использовать самый простой вариант (Создание поля `input` `hidden` и через js в него автоматически добавлять параметр `data` или массив подобных параметров) В Вашем же случае лучше использовать `ajax` запросы. А лучше собрать разом все `data`, поместить в массив и отправить одним запросом на сервер в `php`.

Comment: хорошее предложение, насчет  собрать все data, но как это сделать и как ajax-ом их передать?

Comment: Сейчас напишу пару примеров. У Вас `jquery` или чистый `js`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример с передачей в `input`. (Дальше получаем файл в нужном скрипте как через обычную форму.

```js
window.onload = function () { //Выполнить при загрузке
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('[data-elementor-id]'); // Находим элементы с нужным атрибутом.
    var newArr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        newArr.push(elems[i].dataset.elementorId); // Записываем в массив полученные id из атрибутов.
    }
    document.getElementById('dataset').value = newArr; // Вариант первый - записываем в скрытое поле input или можно его создать через js сразу при действии
}
```

```html
<div data-elementor-type="section" class="data" data-elementor-id="1012">
    <section class="container page-intro">
        <div class="header-text__links"></div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <h1>Пурум Пум Пум</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <p>Парам Пам Пам</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
<div data-elementor-type="section" class="data" data-elementor-id="1013">
    <section class="container page-intro">
        <div class="header-text__links"></div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <h1>Пурум Пум Пум</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <p>Парам Пам Пам</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
<div data-elementor-type="section" class="data" data-elementor-id="1014">
    <section class="container page-intro">
        <div class="header-text__links"></div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <h1>Пурум Пум Пум</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <p>Парам Пам Пам</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" id="dataset">
    <button formmethod="post">Отправить данные дата</button>
</form>
```

Второй вариант через `ajax`

```js
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('[data-elementor-id]'); // Находим элементы с нужным атрибутом.
    var newArr = [];
    for (let i=0;i<elems.length;i++){
        newArr.push(elems[i].dataset.elementorId); // Записываем в массив полученные id из атрибутов.
    }

    var string = JSON.stringify(newArr);
    
    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    /*  Составляем строку запроса и кладем данные, строка состоит из:
    пути до файла обработчика ? имя в GET запросе где будет лежать значение запроса data */
    const url = "ajax_quest.php?data=" + string + ";

    /* Здесь мы указываем параметры соединения с сервером, т.е. мы указываем метод соединения GET,
    а после запятой мы указываем путь к файлу на сервере который будет обрабатывать наш запрос. */
    request.open('GET', url);

    // Указываем заголовки для сервера, говорим что тип данных, - контент который мы хотим получить должен быть не закодирован.
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-url');

    // Здесь мы получаем ответ от сервера на запрос, лучше сказать ждем ответ от сервера
    request.addEventListener("readystatechange", () => {

        /*   request.readyState - возвращает текущее состояние объекта XHR(XMLHttpRequest) объекта,
        бывает 4 состояния 4-е состояние запроса - операция полностью завершена, пришел ответ от сервера,
        вот то что нам нужно request.status это статус ответа,
        нам нужен код 200 это нормальный ответ сервера, 401 файл не найден, 500 сервер дал ошибку и прочее...   */
        if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {

            // выводим в консоль то что ответил сервер
            console.log( request.responseText );
        }
    });
```

```html
<div data-elementor-type="section" class="data" data-elementor-id="1012">
    <section class="container page-intro">
        <div class="header-text__links"></div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <h1>Пурум Пум Пум</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <p>Парам Пам Пам</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
<div data-elementor-type="section" class="data" data-elementor-id="1013">
    <section class="container page-intro">
        <div class="header-text__links"></div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <h1>Пурум Пум Пум</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <p>Парам Пам Пам</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
<div data-elementor-type="section" class="data" data-elementor-id="1014">
    <section class="container page-intro">
        <div class="header-text__links"></div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <h1>Пурум Пум Пум</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <p>Парам Пам Пам</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>

<input type="hidden" id="dataset">
```